# Pyplot: How to add mirrored second y-axis instead of negative values?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, iteration, resources, axis

In pyplot, how could I add a second y-axis where normally the negative values would be? The y-values should be increasing away from the shared x-axis.

Above the x-axis I want to plot time consumption and below the x-axis space consumption. The x-axis is basically the current iteration.

Comment: Is this a question about relabeling the lower y-axis part? Or do you want to combine two plots into one with a share x-axis? Because if the lower axis had the same values as the upper part, where should matplotlib put a marker at position (1, 2) - below or above the x-axis? Some code/toy data would surely not do any harm.

Comment: Maybe the "mirrored" part was misleading, the lower part will not necessarily have the same values as the upper part. I can try and add some code later.

Comment: So, the part below the x-axis has a y-axis from zero to N but is actually a second subplot containing other data?

Comment: Yes exactly, but of course the x-axis is shared. I guess you are pointing into the direction of a subplot with shared x-axis and somehow inverting the direction of the second subplot's y-axis? If this is the preferred solution, I can probably find out how to do it myself and then post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using [sharex=True](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and [invert_yaxis()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#axis-limits):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(5, 10))

xdata = [2, 1, 5]
data1 = [1, 3, 5]
data2 = [1, 4, 7]

l1 = ax1.plot(xdata, data1, "ro")
l2 = ax2.plot(xdata, data2, "bx")
l3 = ax2.plot(xdata, data1, "g")

#make the appearance more coherent
#remove space between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)   
#invert the y-axis
ax2.invert_yaxis()
#set both plots to the same y-limit
lim = max(max(ax1.get_ylim()), max(ax2.get_ylim()))
ax1.set_ylim(0, lim)
ax2.set_ylim(lim, 0)
#move the x-axis label to the center
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()
#remove the double zero label
yticks2 = ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
yticks2[0].set_visible(False)

#create a common legend
ax1.legend(l1+l2+l3, ["data1", "data2", "again data1"])
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]